# How can I resolved Performance issues with Excel 2013?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, memory

I'm using a dell E6440 laptop with Core i5 CPU and 64-bit windows 7. I'm running Excel 2013. I do a lot of reporting through Excel and of recent I've noticed reduced performance - choppy mouse movements, excel freezing or crashing, slow response to input from keyboard etc.

I do have a lot of macros running in the background as such I have upgraded the RAM to 8GB.

I've run a diagnostic to check the HDD and RAM which the tests have comeback OK. No other programs are experiencing the same performance issues. I've also installed all the latest patches.

Any Ideas on what could be causing this problem?

Comment: Is it only one particular workbook giving you trouble? Or is it all workbooks? Your question sounds like all workbooks are having issues. Your answer to this would help reduce over complicating the fix for Excel if the issue is only one file.

Comment: hi CharlieRB, The problem is with Multiple spreadsheets

Comment: Do all those workbooks have the same description as above with a lot of macros running? And when you say "*macros running*", you mean they are running in the background all the time, or simply that there are a lot of macros available to be run?

Comment: Try disabling the GPU acceleration in Office/Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Office installation options
Start-->run-->appwiz.cpl -->change-->click on installation options tap-->choose also office shared features and and office tools "run all from my computer"-->finnish and reboot your system .

Answer (score 0):

Have you upgraded a previous version of Excel? If so you may have installed a 32bit version.

If performances matter to you, try to uninstall everything office and install the fresh 64bit. Things will be a lot faster!

This solved my performances issues on my Windows 7 enterprise laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Profile the workbooks with the profiler in the free [FormulaDesk](http://www.formuladesk.com) add-in. It should pinpoint any performance problems on the spreadsheet itself ie: formulas, volatile cells etc. Also click the 'Trim Bloated Workbook' button to remove unnecessary blank rows and columns.

*Disclaimer: [FormulaDesk](http://www.formuladesk.com) is my product*

[image]